# Find number of references to a dll

Tags: c#, dll, reference, resharper

We would like to keep track of the number of references that link to a dll.

Something like Resharper provides:
[image]

But then automated so that we can keep track of the number of usages and do something if the number of usages increases from 139 to 139+.

Is there an easy way to do this automatically?

Comment: use Visual Studio  2013

Comment: @Sajeetharan Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably your best bet if you want things returned the Resharper way.

[ReSharper Command Line Tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html)

This blog post provides some additional information:

[ReSharper Code Analysis Goes Beyond Visual Studio](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/03/26/resharper-code-analysis-goes-beyond-visual-studio/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, didn't know about it. I've taken a look at it but I'm not seeing the exact functionality I need.

Comment: If you want this the ReSharper way, I would contact them and see if they are able to point you in the proper direction.  It could be that their documentation is lacking for the command-line tool and it is indeed possible to get what you are looking for.

Comment: I posted on their forum about the issue and they responded that it is not possible at this time.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Thanks for going through the trouble. We're currently testing to see if we can get seomthing to work with VS Roslyn. Looks like it might have what we need.